# Ubuntu Builder ISO File?

Tags: helpfile

I got Ubuntu Builder, the ISO and some packages. However, after build, I did not find my ISO... Where is it stored? Was it stored to what folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ISO is stored in the `/home/ubuntu-builder` To access

Open  the home folder icon on the Ubuntu launcher

Open `file system`

Open `Home directory` there you will see your home directory and ubuntu-builder directory

Open `ubuntu builder` directory and you should see the ISO you made

[image: Example]

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the help :) I didnt know that was my iso. Thank you for your assistance.